# SLF4JBridgeHandler installation via logging.properties configuration file doesn't work

Tags: java, jersey, logback, jersey-1.0, jul-to-slf4j

I have a project and I use:

- Apache Maven 3.3.3
- Project Jersey 1.17
- Spring 3.3.1
- Tomcat 6
- Eclipse IDE

I need to log requests and responses. To achieve it I added LoggingFilter to my `web.xml`:

```
<init-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
     <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <init-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
     <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
 </init-param>
```

I run project in Eclipse and see logging at the Eclipse Console.

Now, I want to use Logback to write log files and to use custom appenders, so I added to my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.13</version>
</dependency>
```

To route all JUL log records to the SLF4J API, I use `org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler`

I tried to install SLF4JBridgeHandler by creating `src/main/resources/logging.properties` with the content:

```
handlers = org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler
```

as it mentioned [here](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html) and nothing was happening.

If I use another approach (Programmatic installation) everything works fine.

Why doesn't it work with `logging.properties` config? What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

The `logging.properties` file should reside on the filesystem (not on class path). And it's path should be specified via system property `java.util.logging.config.file`:

```
java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/logging.properties ...
```